# Java how to realize function template like C++

Tags: java, c++, max

My English is not good. So I try to explain my question in code. Please try to answer me in code. It makes me understand easily.

I have a question: In C++，we can realize that like these codes.

```
int max(int x,int y)
{
   return (x>y)?x:y;
}
float max(float x,float y)
{
   return (x>y)?x:y;
}
```

I can do this to expand code

```
template <class T>
T max(T x, T y)
{
return (x>y)?x:y;
}
```

How can I realize the similar function in Java.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a code translation service. I suggest you take the [tour] and visit the [help] and don't use unrelated tags such as `java` and `c++`. Welcome to SO.

Comment: https://juristr.com/blog/2008/03/java-generics-c-class-templates-vs-java/

Comment: Java doesn't have templates. It has generics which are similar but more restricted.

Comment: Java has a different object model. It doesn't really need the same notion of templates that C++ has. Your question feels a little XY-like to me.

Comment: Use the functions already available in [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-)?

Comment: @M. le Rutte. I want to ask another question. now I have a function void swap(int[] arr , int i , int j ). If I have other array type to change some element. what i show do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics. Because generics do not work with primitives, and objects cannot be compared with greater-than and less-than operators, we must instead restrict the input types to [`Comparable`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (things which can be compared) so that we can use the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method instead:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T first, T second)
{
    return first.compareTo(second) >= 0 ? first : second;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
max(1, 2)
```

will [autobox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) the primitives to [`Integer`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html) (which do implement `Comparable<Integer>`) and return 2.

Comment: thanks a lot. I want to ask another question. If i have a function void swap(int[] arr ,int i ,int j ). How can I expand to any array that I can use this swap function.

Comment: @xychen "I want to ask another question" there's [already a good way for you to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The underlying assumption in the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code is that the `T` type supports the `>` operator. Java doesn't have operator overloading, but the equivalent would be to limit the code to `T`s that implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T x, T y)
{
    if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Or, alternatively, allow the caller to pass a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
public static <T> T max(T x, T y, Comparator<T> cmp)
{
    if (cmp.compare(x, y) > 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, the convention of the contracts of most (maybe all) `max` implementations I've seen is to return the first argument if the two are equal. Yours returns the second. (Not a problem for `Number`s, but potentially could be for other `Comparable` types)

Comment: @Michael I was following OP's c++ code as close as possible, but I agree with this comment

Answer (score -2):

Use generics. They are like templates but work in runtime

```
    package test; 

class BoxPrinter<T> { 
    private T val; 

    public BoxPrinter(T arg) { 
        val = arg; 
    } 

    public String toString() { 
        return "{" + val + "}"; 
    } 

    public T getValue() { 
        return val; 
    } 
    }
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generics-in-java/ 
More examples here

Comment: How does this realize the OP's `max` function?

Comment: public T max(T a, T b) { 
        return (a>b) ? a : b;
    }

Comment: What is the problem with your function? Why does it not work? Are there any errors?

Comment: You didn't provide an actual answer. You just said use generics and provided a generic example that has nothing to do with the max function OP's trying to reproduce.

Comment: @EugeneMart The code in your comment don't even compile because of several errors. Main reason: `T` is a parameter for non primitive types whereas the binary operator `>` may only be used with primitve numbers.